# Why the gap and width of SVG rectangles, drawn consecutively, are uneven when rendered in IE11?

Tags: javascript, svg, browser, internet-explorer-11

The gap and width of SVG rectangles are uneven visually when rendered in Internet Explorer 11.

Consecutive rectangles are drawn having same gap and width but in IE11 the gap and width seem to be visually uneven.

Here is a sample -

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('container'),
        svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"),
        rect,
        i,
        startX = 50,
        startY = 100,
        width = 2,
        height = 200,
        gap = 0.8;

    svg.setAttribute("width", 500);
    svg.setAttribute("height", 500);
    svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
    svg.setAttribute("id", "mysvg");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("fill", "rgba(88,162,213,1)");
        rect.setAttribute("x", startX);
        rect.setAttribute("y", startY);
        rect.setAttribute("width", width);
        rect.setAttribute("height", height);
        svg.appendChild(rect);

        startX += width + gap;
        startY += 1;
        height -= 1;
    }

    container.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with the value being a non-integer for gap (0.8).

If you change gap to 1 it renders consistently. https://jsfiddle.net/6jzcuh6s/

```
    var cont = document.getElementById('container'),
    svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"),
    rect,
    i,
    startX = 50,
    startY = 100,
    width = 2,
    height = 200,
    gap = 1;

svg.setAttribute("width", 500);
svg.setAttribute("height", 500);
svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
svg.setAttribute("id", "mysvg");

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    rect.setAttribute("fill", "rgba(88,162,213,1)");
    rect.setAttribute("x", startX);
    rect.setAttribute("y", startY);
    rect.setAttribute("width", width);
    rect.setAttribute("height", height);
    svg.appendChild(rect);

    startX += width + gap;
    startY += 1;
    height -= 1;
}

container.appendChild(svg);

<div id="container"></div>
```

This is because when you have a non-integer value and everything else is integer based, there will be uneven mapping of pixels when drawn in the browser.
If you zoom in and out of the svg you can see the gapping changes.

[image: Chrome with .8 gap]

chrome with .8 gap, 
notice the same thing you are explaining in IE11
[image: Chrome with 1.0 gap]

chrome with 1.0 gap, no uneven spacing.

This has to do with pixel mapping, it is only drawing shapes from evenly divisible pixels, which means that if you use a decimal it gets truncated.

Comment: I know it. Actually am working on rendering a graph where all the value of width and gap of the plots(svg rectangles) will be in decimal point, i.e., in float values mostly and not in integer, i.e., in whole numbers. Chrome, Firefox renders the svg elements properly with no visual unevenness but IE11 fails.